# How do I texture both sides of a mesh in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the moment I'm creating my mesh and texturing it. This works from one side, but from the other its transparent.

```
        m.name = "TopWallMesh";
        m.vertices = new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(-width, 0f, -height),
            new Vector3(width, 0f, -height),
            new Vector3(-width, 0.1f, -height),
            new Vector3(width, 0.1f, -height)
        };
        m.uv = new Vector2[] {
            new Vector2 (0, 0),
            new Vector2 (0, 1),
            new Vector2 (1, 0),
            new Vector2 (1, 1)
        };
        m.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };
        m.RecalculateNormals();
```

How do I go about fixing this so it's textured on both sides?

Comment: you can create another face with inverted normals

Answer (score 1):

Set Cull to off to your shader to render backface culled.
Here you have an example of doubleside standard shader:

```
Shader "DoubleSided" {
Properties {
     _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
     _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
     //_BumpMap ("Bump (RGB) Illumin (A)", 2D) = "bump" {}
 }
 SubShader {     
     //UsePass "Self-Illumin/VertexLit/BASE"
     //UsePass "Bumped Diffuse/PPL"
     // Ambient pass
    Pass {
     Name "BASE"
     Tags {"LightMode" = "Always" /* Upgrade NOTE: changed from PixelOrNone to Always */}
     Color [_PPLAmbient]
     SetTexture [_BumpMap] {
         constantColor (.5,.5,.5)
         combine constant lerp (texture) previous
         }
     SetTexture [_MainTex] {
         constantColor [_Color]
         Combine texture * previous DOUBLE, texture*constant
         }
     }
 // Vertex lights
 Pass {
     Name "BASE"
     Tags {"LightMode" = "Vertex"}
     Material {
         Diffuse [_Color]
         Emission [_PPLAmbient]
         Shininess [_Shininess]
         Specular [_SpecColor]
         }
     SeparateSpecular On
     Lighting On
     Cull Off
     SetTexture [_BumpMap] {
         constantColor (.5,.5,.5)
         combine constant lerp (texture) previous
        }
    SetTexture [_MainTex] {

         Combine texture * previous DOUBLE, texture*primary
         }
     }
 } 
 FallBack "Diffuse", 1
}
```